# Find 'homeless families' in many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, many-to-many

I have 2 models and one linking them in many-to-many relation.
Like this:

```
    class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :family_in_house
    end

    class House < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :family_in_house
    end

    class FamilyInHouse < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :family
      belongs_to :house
    end
```

And I need to have a separate scope for families that are not associated with any house.

I'm realtively new to RoR and couldn't find the solution myself. I use Rails 3.2.9 if it's necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :family_in_houses

  scope :without_house, includes(:family_in_houses).where( :family_in_houses => {:house_id=>nil} )
end
```